# Ionic 2 proxy not working anymore

Tags: proxy, ionic2

I have a Ionic 2 app with a proxy I user for development when i use `ionic serve`. All was working great with this in my config file :

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/apiv2/",
      "proxyUrl": "https://myapilink.com/apiv2/"
    }
]
```

And in my Ionic provider :

```
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.API_URL = "/apiv2";
    this.data = {};
  }

  call(action, entity, params){

      return new Promise(resolve => {
          let link = this.API_URL;
          let data = JSON.stringify({action: action, entity: entity, params: params});

          this.http.post(link, data)
              .map(res => res.json())
              .subscribe(data => {
                  this.data = data;
                  resolve(this.data);
              }, error => {
                  console.log(error);
              });
      });
  }
```

When I run my Ionic project with `ionic serve`, I can see that the proxies are added : 
`[09:54:50]  Proxy added:/apiv2/ => https://myapilink.com/apiv2/`

But when I run my app, when an API call comes, in my network log I only have 500 errors :

```
POST http://localhost:8100/apiv2/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

But while Ionic server is running, if I go on chrome and enter this URL : `http://localhost:8100/apiv2/`, I have the result of my API, with my JSON return, so the redirection is made. I don't understand where it's coming from

Thank in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

There is some guide in github: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli#service-proxies .
Maybe in the ionic.config.json you should config like this：

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/apiv2/",
      "proxyUrl": "https://localhost:8100/apiv2/"
    }
]
```